# sapui5 form label alignment

Tags: alignment, label, sapui5

how can I set form label property to left currently by default it align to Right I check in console i.e. default css working

```
.sapMLabel {
    text-align: end !important;
}
```

I want it to align to Left how to achieve same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a textAlign property of sap.m.Label.

```
<Label text="Sales order" textAlign="Right"/>
```

Comment: Thanks 
also we can add css for globle change
.sapMLabel {
  
   // text-align: Begin !important;
}

Comment: Hi MIT, it should not be the recommended way as you are modifying the global css. so the labels of your whole application are aligning right.: )

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the html and the css for the surrounding tags. 
But in most cases, this should do the trick:

```
.sapMLabel {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: how I can update .sapMLabel which load from default sapui5 liablary.css I am trying to apply new css on label it but it not works  <Label text="Sales order" class="formLabel"/>